# Particle system removes my particles when I render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm using a hair particle system to make a forest with the density determined by a separate UV mapped texture. When I set it up it looks correct:

[image: correct particle system]

But when I render it seems to remove most the particles and only leaves some blocks behind. I have no idea how to fix this:

[image: faulty result]

Here is the blend file: https://mega.co.nz/#!8E5VkDaJ!PsExHPP7LQNxk8Ry7xco9B3iO1xKrDhELS6wEszjM_Q

Comment: No child particles. Don't know what details I could give, so here is the blend file: https://mega.co.nz/#!8E5VkDaJ!PsExHPP7LQNxk8Ry7xco9B3iO1xKrDhELS6wEszjM_Q

Comment: Have you tried *use modifier stack*?

Comment: This seems a bug report.  The viewport render looks fine and then as soon as I do a Camera render; the Viewport render breaks and now starts doing the same thing as the camera render.  When I reload the scene, the Viewport render is fine again until I do a camera render->  then both are broken again.

Comment: The subsurf modifier is closely related the erratic behavior.  Not sure why though.  Try enabling and disabling it.  Also try changing the viewport subsurf levels.  They all change the layout of the trees.

Comment: Yeah it's weird. Luckily the answer by TheAdamGaskins provides a superior work around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just quick side note, I'm a huge fan of this style of art. You've done a really good job on this, and I've enjoyed looking around your .blend and learning a little bit about how you did it :)

You can tell something is immediately not right if you jiggle the Display percentage, under particle settings, a little. It will cause a lot of trees to disappear like when you perform a render.

[image]

Blender seems to be a little confused, and this might be a bug.

Anyway, the underlying issue is that you're using a texture to change the density. If this is your emitter:

[image]

This is your mask texture:

[image]

Then when applied, it simply deletes the trees outside the mask:

[image]

And that's how texture density masks work. You can prove this by setting the particle count to a small number like 10. If you count up all the trees you see, it will definitely be less than 10, if there are any at all.

But what you *want* is for it to constrain all the trees to your mask. The way to do that is with vertex groups.

### Step 1: Remove the texture mask.

Under particle settings, click here:

[image]

Scroll down, set Density to 0 and uncheck it:

[image]

At this point, you should see *all* 40,000 trees. You may want to go ahead and lessen the emitter amount, because your computer will probably be running slow. Also, be sure to check `Use Modifier Stack`.

[image]

### Step 2: Create the vertex group

Now one way to create the vertex group would be to use weight painting, but that can be a pain, and you already have a texture you want to use, so we'll convert that texture into a vertex group.

First, create a new vertex group, and call it something you'll be able to remember.

[image]

Go to your particle settings, and assign the new vertex group to density.

[image]

Nothing should happen just yet. Almost there. Add a new Vertex Weight Edit modifier:

[image]

Use these magic settings:

[image]

And Voila!

[image]
[*Click for full size*](http://theadamgaskins.com/u/1417630773.png)

*Note: I turned down the emitter count to about 3,000 in the photo to decrease render times.*

Comment: It seems a bit complex but it's nice and clear answer!

Comment: @TARDISMaker It's not as complicated as it looks, I promise :) Blender is just confusing sometimes. For example, it doesn't make sense that the vertex group density works different from the texture density. They're called the same thing, so you would think they would work the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much! This technique will also be handy for my future particle systems. I always used that density thing and did indeed notice I needed way more particles than should be necessary. Also thanks for the compliment on the style!

Comment: You said you liked the style, here you can see the resulting animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti724qA5XEQ 
I would have liked to do more, but it was a real rush job as I only had three days. Can make some last small adjustments on monday, but that's it. It's for an item which explains the use of air cushions to reduce earthquake effects. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark the question as answered. Thanks again.